# I cannot get /mnt/hgfs in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: vmware, ruby, rails

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 in VMWare 5.i need to mount my project(using aptana studio 3,Ruby on Rails project in my workspace).I have even shared workspace in VMWare.but still i cannot see it when i run `cd /mnt/hgfs/my workspace/project_1`,there is no hgfs folder in mnt.I have ruby on 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have to run like

```
cd /mnt/hgfs/my\ workspace/project_1
```

Comment: i am sorry,but i have tried this..cd /mnt/hgfs/...i get error as no such file or directory as hgfs.i even browse from desktop...i cannot see hgfs...mnt folder is empty.

Comment: is it an issue related to VMware tools.....i have installed after installing Ubuntu.....or i have even seen few blogs that says install Vmware tools first and then go for Installing Ubuntu....Im confused...